# How to create Report to count Record on opportunity Stage wise Won in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I need to create a report that would be count Records on Opportunity stage. It means, for Ex: I have total 100 records which is closed Won. so I need to show Closed won Records as per their stage history.
Like: Opportunity Stage                                      Record Count

1. Prospecting >> qualification >> Closed Won    ===         50
2. Prospecting >> qualification >> Need Analysis >> value proposition >> closed Won === 25
3. Prospecting >> qualification >> value proposition >> perception analysis>> negotiation>> closed Won == 25

So, I want to calculate Record on this stage basis.
Please give me some solution on it.

I try to create a opportunity History Report using From Stage and To stage filed and using date for group by Opportunity Type.
and also try so many way but it doesn't show me the record count as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it in 2 steps.

First report similar to this (I had to anonymise my stage names), it's just "Opportunity History" type, group rows by oppty name, columns by "To Stage", don't show details.

[image]

And then maybe you could take [reporting snapshot](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_about_analytic_snap&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) of that to helper object and run final report on that?

If that's not an option... Prepare your data other way. Make a helper text(255) field on oppty and populate it with something like

```apex
List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, 
    (SELECT NewValue
     FROM Histories
     WHERE Field = 'StageName'
     ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE IsWon = true AND HelperField__c = null
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
LIMIT 100];

for(Opportunity o : opps){
    List<String> stages = new List<String>();
    for(OpportunityFieldHistory oh : o.Histories){
        stages.add(String.valueOf(oh.NewValue));
    }
    o.HelperField__c = String.join(stages, ' -> ').abbreviate(255);
}
update opps;
```

Give it a go and if it looks promising - data fix for existing records + trigger? nightly job? that'd run it for opps as they close?